# How to know if a page is open/added to Navigator stack?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have three pages each one is a `StatefulWidget` put into separate dart files named:

```
welcome.dart
page_01.dart
page_02.dart
```

I open each page using `pushNamed` function of `Navigator` like so:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/pageName');
```

this is made possible using custom `RouteGenerator` added to my app main `MaterialApp` widget.

Lets say I open **welcome** page, then **page_01** then **page_02** in this order. now I am looking at **page_02** which is at the top of Navigation stack. I want to know if **page_01** is open/added to Navigation stack and its index number, which in this case should have index of **1**.

How to know if a page is open in navigation stack and get its index number ?

Answer (score 11):

The state class of `Navigator` holds a list of widgets named `List<Route<dynamic>> _history`.

Since this value is kept `private` and there is no public `getter` provided, we can not find what is the status of pushed widgets at any given moment.

However, `NavigatorState` does provide some getters to know the status of the extreme ends of `_history`:

1. `bool get isCurrent` // if the current widget/route is at the top of the stack
2. `bool get isActive`  // if the current widget/route is on the navigator
3. `bool get isFirst`  // if the current widget/route is at the bottom of the stack

Since none of them takes any widget/route as parameters these getters only use `this` to produce results for each status queries. There is no way we can get information about widgets that are in the stack but are not being rendered at the moment of the query.

I am afraid I couldn't find any other details to get more about status of other routes.

I have referred to `navigator.dart` file for these details since most of the properties are kept private, online API documentation is not helpful.

If somebody can come up with more details, just let me know. :D

Comment: Hello! Just guessing... how or where to get the `NavigationState`? Thanks!

Comment: If you pass a key to the Navigator widget, then you can call `key.currentState`